# WebSphere Portal clicking links prompts with a file download

Tags: ibm, websphere

I created a new Rational Software Architect workspace pointing to an existing WAS/WebSphere Portal 8.5 profile.

Everything builds without an error, I launch the server, no errors.

However when I try to log in as an administrator, after entering username and password, I am prompted with a download.gz file download which contains the header of the welcome web page.

I click refresh and can reach the "Welcome to WebSphere Portal Administration" page, but once again every link I click prompts me with a file download.

When I go back to the logs, it stack traces something awful, with:
    com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet handleException EJPEJ0070E: 
                                     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     com/bombardier/web/common/WCMUtil.getCategoryUUIDs(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;

Also get EJPEI0175E mentioning the custom theme that is used. It is clearly theme related.

I spent the day without figuring it out. Any help greatly appreciated !

Best regards,
Bert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

The application had some projects that were shared libraries that needed to be exported as jars and placed under PortalServer/shared/app

The Portal then had to be restarted.

The IBM reference is here:
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Managing+WebSphere+Portal+6.1+Environments#action=openDocument&res_title=P61t2h&content=pdcontent

Hope this saves someone some grief.